# My xen installation is rebooting randomly. How do I track the error?

Tags: linux, xen

I have a test xen installation that is using the gfx_passthrough option.

It appears to run fine. However, after about 15minutes the whole xen installation reboots for no obvious reason.

I don't see anything in the logs that would hint at the reason.  How can I track/narrow this down?  i.e. there is nothing logged in /usr/log/messages, or any of the xen log files.

Should I enable core dumps and try to debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force the installation to not reboot on error and also to enable logging on panics, add "noreboot" to Xen's boot options. Also, check your BIOS for power options relating to the CPUs. Turn off any low power settings as this has been known to cause Xen to crash and burn.

Comment: Interestingly, putting that option in stopped it rebooting.  It's not crashing either.